# Embedded youtube API player copyright issue on android

Tags: youtube-api, android-youtube-api

New android youtube api allows developer to embed and play videos in the third party app.
I made android app that shows list of youtube videos and show video in the app (not using youtube official app)
In this case, I wonder there is no copyright issue at all. I know youtube can play ad on the player but most case it just looks like my app is providing content directly.